# Looping over a delimited list of characters in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

So my XML follows:

```
<Classes>  
  <Classes_Per_Term>  
    <Course>ENC1101</Course>
    <Ref_Code>111111</Ref_Code>
    <Days_of_Week>M</Days_of_Week>
  </Classes_Per_Term>
  <Classes_Per_Term>  
    <Course>ENC1101</Course>
    <Ref_Code>111222</Ref_Code>
    <Days_of_Week>M W F</Days_of_Week>
  </Classes_Per_Term>  
</Classes>
```

I need output to look like this

```
ENC1101 111111 M  
ENC1101 111222 M  
ENC1101 111222 W  
ENC1101 111222 F
```

I am printing the `<Course>` and `<Ref_Code>` with a `<xsl:value-of>` call and using a newline to hop to the next row. I am unsure how to set a loop inside the `<Days_of_Week>` node.

There are all sorts of Day combinations - I need a row for each day a specific reference meets.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, you have to have a single root element to your input XML, else it's not well-formed:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Classes>
  <Classes_Per_Term>  
    <Course>ENC1101</Course>
    <Ref_Code>111111</Ref_Code>
    <Days_of_Week>M</Days_of_Week>
  </Classes_Per_Term>
  <Classes_Per_Term>  
    <Course>ENC1101</Course>
    <Ref_Code>111222</Ref_Code>
    <Days_of_Week>M W F</Days_of_Week>
  </Classes_Per_Term>  
</Classes>
```

### XSLT 2.0 Solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Classes/Classes_Per_Term">
    <xsl:variable name="course" select="Course"/>
    <xsl:variable name="refcode" select="Ref_Code"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(Days_of_Week, ' ')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($course, ' ', $refcode, ' ', ., '&#xa;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Yields**

```
ENC1101 111111 M
ENC1101 111222 M
ENC1101 111222 W
ENC1101 111222 F
```

**as requested.**

Comment: Thanks! I accepted but will upvote when I have the rep.

Answer (score 0):

For an XSLT 1.0 solution it is necessary to generate a sequence without `tokenize()`. This solution uses no recursion and uses the nodes of the document as a generator to provide the position values and filters on the length of the string.

The solution is not robust to varying length days of the week, or to applications where the number of tokens can exceed the total number of nodes in the document. In such cases, a more comprehensive parser in a recursive structure may be more appropriate.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
    <xsl:template match="Classes_Per_Term">
    <xsl:variable name="Classes" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="Days" select="Days_of_Week" />
        <xsl:for-each select="//*">
            <xsl:variable name="Day" select="substring($Classes/Days_of_Week, position() * 2 - 1, 1)" />
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= (string-length($Days) + 1) div 2">
                <xsl:value-of select="$Classes/Course" />
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Classes/Ref_Code" />
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Day" />
                <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The requirement to have a top-level node in the document remains.

Comment: Why avoid recursion in exchange for something so brittle?

Comment: If the size of the source document is not well bounded, then recursion may not be appropriate. If your brittleness comment refers to the parser, then that is an XSL 1.0 limitation, not of the approach.

Comment: Most XSLT processors optimize tail recursion to iteration. When properly implemented a recursive solution is no need to be concerned.

Answer (score 0):

For XSLT 1.0 this is almost trivially solved through recursion.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="Classes_Per_Term">
    <xsl:param name="days" select="Days_of_Week" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-before(concat($days, ' '), ' ')" />
    <xsl:if test="$day">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(Course, ' ', Ref_Code, ' ', $day, '&#xA;')" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
        <xsl:with-param name="days" select="substring-after($days, ' ')" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output as required

```
ENC1101 111111 M
ENC1101 111222 M
ENC1101 111222 W
ENC1101 111222 F
```

This template keeps calling itself until it runs out of `$days`, printing one `$day` per call.

http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKw4